# TForm Resource not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I had to format my computer and reinstall RAD Studio 10.4.

I have many projects. All projects have been recompiled and are running, except for one project that is showing strange behavior.

Any new form I add to the project, when I create the Form, I get the message:

> Project XXX raised exception class EResNotFound with the message 'Resource TFormYYY not found'

Also, if I add a new `TMenuItem` to `TMainMenu`, the new item does not appear.

It happens only in this particular project.

I tried a few things:

- Deleted the project `.res`, `.dproj`, and `.dproj.local` files.
- Compared the project options with the options of other projects, which is OK.
- Restored a backup copy.

I suppose this is a resource issue, but I could not find a solution.

Update: if I change the project name everything works fine!

Comment: You said that you've checked the project options.  Does that include checking the paths (search path, etc.) in project options?

Comment: Based on your description I'm guessing your previous Delphi installation might have different settings for default folder locations than your current Delphi installation. Since Delphi stores in Delphi project only settings that have been changed from default setting it is possible that such customized paths were never stored in your project file as at the time they were considered default. So compare path between all of your projects to find difference. Or jet even better compare where resources for old forms are located in comparison where resources for new forms are generated.

Comment: Does every pas file, which has a corresponding dfm file, has a proper {$i *.dfm} entry in this project?

Comment: Does the problem recur if you change the project name back?  On the off-chance that it is some edge case related to the actual project name, what is that project name (when it exhibits this behaviour)?

Comment: First of all, thank you, Guys. Philip, I checked all the paths. The other projects compile and run fine. Warior, I didn't change the defaults. Coder, every dfm file contains the entry and Deltics, yes, the problem returns if I return the original project name. I tried to erase any file related to the project name, but the problem remains. I'm sticking to the new name. Thank you Guys again.